# How do I compile AssaultCube on Mac? libintl.h missing

Tags: c++, macos

I can't get AssaultCube to compile on Mac. I've downloaded the latest source and have opened the Xcode project inside (since running "make" gives me the error "'INTL/libintl.h' file not found"). I have Xcode installed, and I use it regularly to compile my own code, but their code just won't work.

First of all, the source has a syntax error. It gives me a type redefinition error here:

```
typedef unsigned int GLhandleARB;   /* shader object handle */
```

So I commented that out, hoping it wouldn't be important. Secondly, there are Mach-O Linker errors everywhere about libintl. And there are also some errors about ov_read, which appears to be an OGG player.

I went and installed gettext twice to get libintl and downloaded a libintl package for OS X… make still won't work, and Xcode won't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problems. Their project file is just messed up. First, you have to relink all the libraries. In the Frameworks folder of the Xcode folder in the source, there are things like INTL.framework that you have to manually link. Second, you have to set the build type to 32-bit.

Now all I have to do is fix the runtime errors I'm getting. Honestly, why can't it just compile and run?

**Update:** Here are the exact steps for the latest release. I didn't have to do as much to make it work as last time, and the gamma glitch is fixed now. I don't know if I have some libraries installed that you won't have, but if it fails to build due to missing libraries, you can probably get them from MacPorts. Please comment if there are any missing libraries, and I'll update this:

```
# grab the src first
git clone https://github.com/assaultcube/AC ac
cd ac
git checkout 76eb031 # latest release as of 1/29/2017; I goofed last time by just taking the latest commit, which had bugs
open ./source/xcode/assaultcube.xcodeproj # should open Xcode
```

In Xcode:

- Select "assaultcube" as your build target.
- Change target architecture to 32-bit
- Go `glext.h`, and comment out anything that gives an error about type redefinition when you try to build. For me, this was `typedef unsigned int GLhandleARB;`, `typedef ptrdiff_t GLintptrARB;`, and `typedef ptrdiff_t GLsizeiptrARB;`
- Build. Go into your targets folder, and find `assaultcube.app`. You could also build the launcher, but there are resources missing in the launcher source for some reason that I don't feel like finding, so just download the compiled Mac launcher/game release from https://github.com/assaultcube/AC/releases/download/v1.2.0.2/AssaultCube_v1.2.0.2.dmg, and symlink (`ln -s [source] [destination]`) the `assaultcube.app` you just built into `AssaultCube.app/contents/gamedata`. Should replace an existing .app.
- All set. Edit, build, and open the launcher you just symlinked into to test.

Comment: Hey - would you be able to reproduce the steps by any chance? I need to build AssaultCube for Mac as well. Maybe make a PR to AssaultCube repository if you can? Thanks.

Comment: In the end, it compiled and ran but had that "gamma" glitch where the colors get messed up whenever you set the gamma. But sure, I'll try redoing the steps when I get home today, and I'll update my answer then. I should have put the steps in my answer in the first place; sorry, SO.

Comment: @ScalaWilliam OK, I updated my answer with steps. Let me know if you run into issues with libraries, and I'll further update it.